# drop down menu not working on ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, drop-down-menu, click, hover

I have an issue with my navigation menu.  It's basically a logo image that when hovered a submenu slides down and then slides up when not hovered on.  It works fine on desktops but  the issue I am having it with mobiles devices.  Specifically the iPad.  For some reason the iPhone seems to translate it OK but on the iPad the first time you click the image the drop down menu slides down and then up quickly and will not appear again.  I have been searching the net for a solution and have tried rewriting the menu completely to use click instead but still haven't had it work properly on an iPad.  If someone could help me or point me in the right direction I would REALLY appreciate it!!

I've also put the sections of code in [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newbie2012/jCMrX/)

```
<div id="button">
<ul class="hover">
    <li class="hoverli">
        <img src="assets/images/menu_logo.jpg" width="210" height="160" class="menu_class"/>
        <ul class="file_menu">
            <li><a href="ourwork.html">our work</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about/about.html">about</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="#"><a href="#">blog</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".hoverli").hover(

function () {
    $('ul.file_menu').slideDown('medium');
},

function () {
    $('ul.file_menu').slideUp('medium');
});

$(".file_menu li").hover(

function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown('medium');
},

function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp('medium');
});
});
```

the css

```
#newmenu {
position: absolute;
height: 32px;
width: 184px;
left: 35px;
top: 100px;
margin: auto;
}
ul, li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}
#submenu {
display:none;
width:100px;
position: relative;
left: 110px;
font-family: helvetica;
font-size:12px;
}
#submenu li {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: relative;
}
#submenu li a {
color:#00000;
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px;
display:block;
text-align: right;
padding-right: 13px
}
.file_menu li a:hover {
color: #585858;
}
.blog {
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and have since stopped using JavaScript for this. Use the CSS :checked pseudo-selector: http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: thanks Kevin I will take a look at that link and see ifI can figure something out.  This seems like it would be a common issue so I'm surprised I haven't found many solutions on the web!

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, touch devices (Android included) don't handle Hover or Mouse events. Consider using .click() or .change(), which I have found to be especially useful on DDL or other menu/filtering behavior.